# Problems loading an image with OpenGL

Tags: java, image, opengl, load, lwjgl

I have a problem loading my image. This is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5XML.jpg. The black spaces shouldn't be there. I don't know if there's something wrong with my image or my code. I've tried other images and some work just fine with this code, some don't.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.Texture;
import org.newdawn.slick.opengl.TextureLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader;
import org.newdawn.slick.Color;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public void init() {
    try {
        texture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("sprites/playButton.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void render() {
    texture.bind();
    Color.white.bind();

    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(400-getWidth()/2,250);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(400+getWidth()/2,250);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(400+getWidth()/2,250+getHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(400-getWidth()/2,250+getHeight());
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

This is the main render function.

```
public void start() {
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
        Display.setInitialBackground(255, 255, 255);
        Display.create();
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // init OpenGL here
    MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu();
    mainMenu.init();

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);        
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);                    

    GL11.glClearColor(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f);                
    GL11.glClearDepth(1);                                       

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GL11.glViewport(0,0,800,600);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        // render OpenGL here
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        mainMenu.render();

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(100);
    }
```

Comment: I think the problem lies with your texture loading code. Can you perhaps post that too? (Or are you using a library to load your textures?)

Comment: Regarding this line: GL11.glClearColor(255.0f, 255.0f, 255.0f, 0.0f);
Note that openGL colours range between 0 and 1. Also, the 0 alpha of the background might be throwing some things off. I'd recommend trying to set it to 1. Unfortunately I don't believe LWJGL supports transparent windows.

Comment: Try calling `System.out.println(ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("sprites/playButton.png"));` what does it print?

Comment: @Bartvbl I added some of the libraries, there is no other texture loading code. I also set the range colours and alpha to one, yet nothing changed.

Comment: @Vallentin I seem to be not able to successfully print it as it keeps giving me errors (syntax error on tokens). After all it's my first attempt in lwjgl.

Comment: Ah, you're using the slick 2D texture loader. If I recall I've had problems with that one too when I tried to use it. I ended up writing my own at the time. It's old and crude, but feel free to use it :) : https://github.com/bartvbl/CoopPuzzler/blob/master/CoopPuzzler/src/client/gl/Texture.java

Comment: ..To elaborate a bit on that: I think what the problem is is that the texture loader allocates an image that is too large for the image you're trying to load. That's what causes the black background; not all of the texture created in openGL is filled with pixels from your image. Not sure if that is actually the case, but it seems quite similar to problems I've had with it in the past.